# Usage of tensors in physics

Tags: differential-geometry, relativity, tensor-calculus

As I understand it, tensors are multi-linear maps that map vectors (and dual vectors) to real (or complex) numbers, but I'm hoping to gain some intuition as to why they are useful in physics.

Is it simply because they are intrinsically geometric objects and thus exist independently of coordinate systems and are therefore useful in describing physical phenomena, since the equations that do so should be covariant? This would be particularly true in relativity which is constructed using differential geometry, where tensors are the natural objects to consider.
Also, would another reason be that they can be used to describe linear relationships between vectors, for example the stress tensor, which relates the normal vector of a surface to the stress vector along the surface, and thus perpendicular to this normal vector?!

**Edit**

Of course, scalars and vectors are themselves special cases of tensors (namely rank 0 and rank (1,0) tensors respectively), and one can more or less intuitively "picture" these objects and why they are used in physics (to represent rotationally invariant quantities (scalars) and quantities that have directional dependence, such as forces (vectors)). But I was really wondering about the usage of more general, higher rank tensors in physics

Comment: I was under the impression (perhaps incorrectly) that a 3-vector, for instance, is a specific type of rank-1 tensor and a scalar would be a rank-0 tensor.  So I am confused because it seems to me that one cannot do physics without tensors.  Have I misunderstood something in your question?

Comment: @honeste_vivere Yes, they are. My question pertains to more general, higher rank tensors. Perhaps I should edit the question to make this point more explicit.

Comment: You answered your own question: Tensors are useful in the mathematical description of physics because they are manifestly coordinate-independent objects, and physics should not (other than covariantly) depend on coordinates. I'm not sure what kind of "intuition" you want to gain about that. What physical intuition you should develop depends on the *specific tensors* you are considering in their *specific physical context* - the stress tensor requires a different physical picture than, say, the electromagnetic field strength.

Comment: @ACuriousOne   Ah ok. To be honest, I mainly wanted to check that I understand the motivation for using tensors in physics, in particular their usage in general relativity. I can picture vectors (and scalars) in my head, but I have to admit, I struggle to picture higher rank tensors, other than accepting that they are useful for describing physical quantities such as the electromagnetic field strength (describing the electromagnetic field of a physical system in spacetime)....

Comment: ... or the stress-energy tensor in GR (which describes the energy density and flux of energy and momentum of matter fields in spacetime).

Answer (score -1):

The usage of tensors in Physics, came about as a fortuitous "adaptation" to deal with the increased complexity of the Physics problems being investigated.  The need to express more and more complex equations as succinctly as possible required a "shorthand" - and tensors came to the rescue.